# Setting up VPN on Centos with router doing dhcp

Tags: vpn, centos, dhcp, pptp

I've successfully setup PPTP VPN on my CentOS 5 server and can connect to it. I've set it up to use the IP range 10.0.1.50-60 and this works and we can ping each other but from what I can tell these IP addresses just exist on the server and not the actual network and is probably because my router is the DHCP server.

Is what I'm doing possible so the VPN server is not the DHCP server? Can the VPN server forward the requests for IP's to the router so that it is part of the network?

Apologies if I'm asking the wrong questions, networking isn't really my forte

Comment: At least of what I know, you can do static address bindings using a RADIUS server.